# Conditionally publish changes to a Combine subscriber?

Tags: swift, combine

I have an @Published field that dictates whether the user is currently in offline mode.

```
class RequestStatus: ObservableObject {
    
    static var shared = RequestStatus()
    
    @Published var offlineModeActive: Bool = false
    
    private init() {}
    
}
```

Throughout my app, I use the Combine framework to subscribe to changes in this field and perform some work.

```
import Combine

class ExampleClass {
        
     var offlineModeCancellable: AnyCancellable

     init() {

          self.offlineModeCancellable = RequestStatus.shared.$offlineModeActive.sink(receiveValue: { offlineModeActive in
                
               // Perform work
                
          })
     }
}
```

This works fine, however, when I run unit tests I do not want changes on this field to be published because I want to set up the environment of the test manually.

Therefore, I added in a field called `shouldPublishChanges` that defines whether changes should be published. If this is set to true, only then will I manually call the `objectWillChange.send()` method.

```
class RequestStatus: ObservableObject {
    
    static var shared = RequestStatus()
    
    var shouldPublishChanges: Bool = false
    
    var offlineModeActive: Bool = false {
        willSet {
            if shouldPublishChanges {
                objectWillChange.send()
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    private init() {}
    
}
```

I then updated my Combine subscriber to subscribe to changes on the `RequestStatus.shared.objectwillChange` value meaning it should only receive a value when shouldPublishChanges is set to true (or so I thought).

```
import Combine

class ExampleClass {
        
     var offlineModeCancellable: AnyCancellable

     init() {

          self.offlineModeCancellable = RequestStatus.shared.objectWillChange.sink(receiveValue: {
                
               // Perform work
                
          })
     }
}
```

However, even though `shouldPublishChanges` is set to `shouldPublishChanges`, if I change the `offlineModeActive` value, the value is published and the subscriber still receives the update and performs the work.

So, how do I conditionally publish changes to a Combine subscriber?

The only other idea I have is to have one field that stores the value and another field for the publisher. Then, only when I want to publish changes to this field will I update the published value.

```
import Combine

class RequestStatus: ObservableObject {
    
    private init() {}
    
    static var shared = RequestStatus()
    
    var shouldPublishChanges: Bool = false
    
    private(set) var offlineModeActivePublisher = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(false)
    
    private(set) var offlineModeActive: Bool = false
    
    func updateOfflineModeActive(offlineModeActive: Bool) {
        
        self.offlineModeActive = offlineModeActive
        
        if shouldPublishChanges {
            offlineModeActivePublisher.value = offlineModeActive
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

However:

1. Requires a lot of boiler-plate code for each field I want to do this for
2. I have two values that can be out of sync (this is less of a concern as `shouldPublishChanges` is set once and never changed)
3. I feel like there is a better way of achieving the same thing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can’t you just avoid changes on that published value? Where are those happening? Otherwise can’t you inject a mock in the test for this class, so that the mock would not produce values at all for this publisher?

Comment: @valeCocoa I need to set up the environment (for instance in offline mode) to check certain code paths in the tests, so the published values have to be changed. ```RequestStatus``` is a singleton containing other published variables that get changed throughout the codebase as they have to be shared. I guess I could mock the singleton and store a variable on any class that uses it...

Comment: You might as well keep `RequestStatus` as a singleton with a `shared` or `default` or `current` shared unique static instance, and also make it possible to instantiate configurable instances.